# I can not open rpt file with VS 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2008

because when I try to open an rpt file from the Solution Explorer, not open in VS 2010 but with the file editor of the Crystal Report, the 2008 version let me, any idea why this happens? thanks

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed Crystal Reports for VS2010? VS2010 doesn't come with Crystal Reports installed by default

Comment: that must be it, I'll try right now, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Note the same stuff here:  [Crystal Reports Problem with .net 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192045/crystal-reports-problem-with-net-4)

You may need to add to your application's config file.