# Crystal Reports Problem with .net 4

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I've worked with Crystal Reports in .net 3.5 before, but since upgrading to .Net 4.0 I'm facing this error:

" Error 5   The type or namespace name 'CrystalDecisions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\Users\aligoglos\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WPF\ReportTest\ReportTest\CrystalReport1.cs    14  11  ReportTest "

I installed Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010, but my error is still unresolved.

Thanks to all.

Comment: what is your environment wpf or win forms?

Answer (score 4):

If you have SAP Crystal Reports, version for Visual Studio 2010, here's what you have to do:

When using ADO.NET with the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0, the following setting must be added to the application’s configuration file:

```
<configuration>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

I got this information from a PDF on Crystal Reports from  here:

http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/index?rid=/library/uuid/e06b8953-a62b-2d10-38b9-ca71f747e2b1&utm_source=crvs2010&utm_medium=lp&utm_campaign=supp_platforms

I hope this helps.